# Cant login in asp.net form as previously registered user

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I used the Login control in my ASP.NET form.A database was created- ASPNETDB.
But once I create a user and then execute the form next time,I cant login, i.e., I've to register as a new user everytime I simulate the web form. The code cant retrieve my previously stored login id and password.How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you checked that the user exists in the DB? There may be a problem when registering which is not appropriately communicated.

Comment: Can you verify that the data is being stored in the ASPNETDB database? You should see entries in the `aspnet_Membership' and `aspnet_Users` tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be that the database file is been copied to the output directory everytime you run your application and overriding the previous copied file that contains the registration data.

If that was the problem, you can solve it by change the database file's `Copy To Output Directory` property value from `always copy` to `copy if newer`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution #1: Under the "project" tab in Visual Studio, go to ASP.NET configuration. Make sure that the "active" check box is checked, under security, manage users (ASP.NET default login tables).

Solution #2: Use your login tables.

Solution #3: Still searching for it.